Caratheodory extension for $\pi$-systems?
The Caratheodory extension theorem assures us of a unique extension of a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal{A}_0$ to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{A}_0)$ it generates.
It is often easier to explicitly construct $\pi$-systems than $\sigma$-algebras. For instance, the collection $\{(0,a]\,\,:\,\,0\leq a \leq 1\}$ is a $\pi$-system on $(0,1]$ that generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Is there instead a way to uniquely (subject to suitable conditions to be specified) extend a "premeasure" on a $\pi$-system $\Pi$ to a measure on $\sigma(\Pi)$? This seems to be suggested by the theorem stating that if two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ on $(\Omega,\sigma(\Pi))$, such that $\mu_1(\Omega)\!=\!\mu_2(\Omega)\!<\!\infty$, agree on $\Pi$, then they agree on $\sigma(\Pi)$.
For instance, in the above example, we can define $\mu_\pi\colon \Pi\to [0,1]$ by setting $\mu_\pi((0,a]) = a$. Is there a way to uniquely extend this to the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\Pi)$? Of course, I am interested in a general answer rather than just this example.

1.Given a premeasure defined on an algebra, the Caratheodory extension to the $\sigma$-algebra is unique. However, if the premeasure id not $\sigma$-finite, there may be other extensions to the $\sigma$-algebra.
2. The Caratheodory extension can be built from a premeasure defined on a semi-algebra.

How do you define a "premeasure" on a $\pi$-system?

@Ramiro With double quotes, it is a notion that is supposed to do for $\pi$-systems what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure do for algebras. The purpose in life of the latter (as far I as am concerned) is to be extended to a unique measure on a \sigma-algebra. This requires $\sigma$-finiteness as you say.

Given a set function $\mu_\pi\colon\Pi!\to![0,1]$ on a $\pi$-system like the example in the question, what additional conditions or constructions are required for it be uniquely extended to $\sigma(\Pi)$ or an algebra or $\lambda$-system generated by $\Pi$? Hope this clarifies.

The additional condition is that the $\pi$-system should be at least a semi-algebra and that $\mu_\pi$ satisfies the definition of a premeasure defined on a semi-algebra.
